# populate first option of dropdown with URL parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, parameters, dropdown

I am trying to set the first option of a dropdown select based on the URL parameter provided.

I am grabbing the URL parameters using the following code:

```
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
  var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1),
    sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
    sParameterName,
    i;

  for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
    sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

    if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
      return typeof sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
    }
  }
  return false;
};
```

The URL may read as follows:

```
https://development.mycompany.com/project/home.php?profile=profile1,profle2&region=&rep=JOHN%20BEASLEY
```

I then can call the getUrlParameter() function to grab the rep parameter:

```
var rep = getUrlParameter('rep');

console.log(rep);

$('#rep').val(rep); // <-- my attempt to set the first option of the dropdown
```

I can see the rep variable in the console.  However, when trying to set the first option of the dropdown select, it remains blank.

Here is the dropdown:

```
<select class="form-control rep" id="rep"></select>
```

I should be able to see 'JOHN BEASLEY' as the selected option in the dropdown.

The dropdown contains 'JOHN BEASLEY', as well as other reps, but it should appear as initially selected. I am perplexed as to why this is not working.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

*** EDIT ***

I am initially populating the dropdown using the following function:

```
function initializeSelect($select, uri, adapt){     
$.getJSON( uri, function( data ) {
    $select.empty().append($('<option>'));      
    $.each(data, function(index, item) {
        var model = adapt(item);
        var $option = $('<option>');
        $option.get(0).selected = model.selected;
        $option.attr('value', model.value)
            .text(model.text)
            .appendTo($select);                     
    });
});
};
```

Then I populate the dropdown like this:

```
initializeSelect($('#rep'), 'api/getReps.php', function (item){ 
return {
    value: item.fullname,
    text: item.fullname,
    style: 'color:black'
}
});
```

Using the above, the dropdown is successfully populated with all of the options in my dB table.

The option JOHN BEASLEY is available in the dropdown list.

Comment: The `<select>` shown is empty? Are you trying to create such an `<option>` or does one already exist with that value?

Comment: The option already exists in the dropdown.  I am trying to get the dropdown to show the selected option as the parameter in the URL.

Comment: Then please provide the `<option>` html also as per [mcve]. Another possibility is you are running code shown before the `<select>` exists

Comment: Your [code seems to work as it is](https://jsfiddle.net/e1u7hcrd/) ..?

Comment: @charlietfl - I updated my question to include the function that initially populates the dropdown.

Comment: @Teemu - All of the code works with no errors.  I am just having an issue showing the rep parameter as the selected option in the dropdown.

Comment: Using different selector to set value `#rep` vs `#Rep` and you can't set that value until after you populate it

Comment: But the linked fiddle shows the option your code selected. Setting the value of a select element provides the value to set being already present in the options of the select element, setting a new value doesn't create a new option.

Comment: @charlietfl - Apologies - it was a typo.  The id is #rep.

Comment: OK but you don't show setting value after you populate and my guess is you aren't accounting for `$.getJSON` being asynchronous

Comment: @charlietfl - Could it be that the function that initially populates the dropdown is conflicting with the function that grabs the parameter from the URL?

Comment: No but you need to call it in the getJSON callback when the options exist. You can't set value on a select that doesn't match an **existing** option

Comment: Also note it's far simpler to use URLSearchParams() to get that "rep" from the url string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can just set the select.value only after the select is initialized, like this:

```
function initializeSelect($select, uri, adapt){     
    $.getJSON( uri, function( data ) {
        $select.empty().append($('<option>'));      
        $.each(data, function(index, item) {
            var model = adapt(item);
            var $option = $('<option>');
            $option.get(0).selected = model.selected;
            $option.attr('value', model.value)
                .text(model.text)
                .appendTo($select);                     
        });
        $select.val(getUrlParameter('rep'));
    });
};
```

Comment: YES!!! That worked!  Thank you, sir.  I do appreciate it.